# Why is QTableView's default QHeaderView different from the default QHeaderView?

Tags: c++, qt

In the following minimal example, the vertical header has totally different default behavior (section is set to clickable, selected rows header items are highlighted, ...) from the default behavior of the newly set default horizontal header. Why is that? In my use case I want to create a header derived from `QHeaderViewer`, that shares all the default behavior of `QTableView`'s default header.

```
QTableWidget w;
w.setHorizontalHeader( new QHeaderView( Qt::Horizontal, &w ) );
w.setColumnCount( 2 );
w.setRowCount( 2 );
w.show();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers your question, but it looks like those are the only 2 changes made for `QTableView` headers, so every other behavior is the same, and you can just make those 2 changes for your derived header view, see the source code for more: [QTableViewPrivate::init()](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtableview.cpp?h=dev#n574).